# finite homological dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-dimension

Hi, I found the following in the proof of a theorem:
$ Z \subset Y \times M$ where $M$ is a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$, $Y$ is a scheme and $Z$ is a subscheme of the product, flat over $Y$. Then $\mathcal{O}_Z$ is of finite homological dimension (is quasi-isomorphic to a bounded complex of locally free sheaves), as an $\mathcal{O}_{ Y \times M}$-module. Why? (all schemes are of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$) Thank you.

Comment: This is proved in SGA 6; the main part is in Expos'e I, Corollaire 3.5(b) and the following Example 3.6 (2nd item).  

Comment: Also, probably you should see Cor.4.14 / Def. 4.14.1 and Cor. 5.8.1.  Flatness implies finite Tor dimension.